# Android - AndroidTest doesn't exist

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

So I took over an Android project which doesn't have nor **androidTest** neither **Test** folders in it.

What is the best way to create them? Is there a simple way to generate them?

Thanks a lot,

Edit:

So I created two folders and tests won't launch. I have exact same structure as the ones that is created by default when creating a new project. Gradle plugins are ok.

```
compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
compile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

When I launch a newly created project, we see "test passed"
When I launch mine, nothing happens

Comment: can you put the APP build grade code please :)

Comment: Sure, here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to generate them?

They are simply directories. You create them the same way that you would create any other directories on your developer machine (e.g., `mkdir` from the command line).

Comment: So I did that, copied the exact same code as the one that is created by default in the androidTest when creating new projects. Double-checked gradle plugins and the test won't launch.

Comment: @millinet: Sorry, but I do not know what "the test won't launch" means. Are you getting an error from Gradle or something?

Comment: When right-clicking and selecting run on the test class, the app is compiled but nothing happens. The app is even not launched. The only difference with another app in which tests work is that I manually created the androidTest and Test folders